# Alternate File and Object Stream usage possible?

Tags: java

I have to improve the code of a badly implemented application. One point is to
change how a savefile is written and read. Here's a stripped down version of how
the actual code of output looks like:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
writer.write(foo.getThis() + "\t" + Integer.toString(foo.getThat()) + "\n");
writer.write(bar.getSomething() + "\n");
writer.close();
```

The real code is more complicated and uses lines with defined strings as "section
dividers" which aid to write/read containers with variable sizes. All that as a
single spagetti.
The input happens by reading the file per line and split("\t"), trim() and other
processing in order to get the items to feed into the respective class constructors.

To improve this I'd like to utilize the Serializable interface. As it would be
too much to change all classes at once, I would tend to refactor it class by class.
This would lead to a temporary output file format that mixes String and Object output.
An output example of how I envision this:

```
File f = new File(path);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
oos.writeObject(foo);
String barString = new String(bar.getSomething() + "\n");
fos.write(barString.getBytes());
oos.close();
```

Is it ok to use the two streams in such interchanged way?

Are there other, preferred, methods to support refactoring this?

Comment: No, but why? Why not use `writeUTF()` or indeed `writeObject()` for the strings and avoid the whole problem?

Comment: Its unclear what exactly you're asking. Why the dividers? Is it because you have x instances of ClassA then y instances of ClassB? 
You could always create a class to represent your divider then just write that as an object to the save file too.